# Ubuntu 13.04 Install presents blinking cursor

Tags: installation, 13.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 13.04, but am running into a specific issue, which I suspect may be a graphics issue, but am not sure.

I've downloaded the .iso, verified the md5sum, and burned it to a dvd, both on mac and lubuntu (using brasero).

I can boot from the CD, but I am required to hold/hit a key to enter the menu. However, when I try to install the new version of Ubuntu (I want a clean install) it does nothing other than present a blinking cursor at the top left.

I've checked dmesg for any issues that arose, but am not seeing anything helpful. Also, I ran a memory test, which showed no memory issues.

I'm currently running kernel 3.2.0-35-generic. My graphics card is ATI M64-S, Radeon X2300. HP 6910p.

Thoughts on how to debug this or, ideally, what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer for me was to set the "nomodeset" boot flag.

Full disclosure: I also am running it from a bootable USB, but don't think that the CD itself was the issue.